# Get the result/request object types from a controller in MVC using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, controller

I got all the methods that returns an ActionResult from a dll by reflection using this code:

```
MyAssembly.GetTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
                .Where(d => d.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult" && d.IsPublic);
```

Now, I would like to have the request object and the result object of each controller.

Generally, the structure of a controller in my project is this:

```
[ServiceControllerResult(typeof(MyControllerResult))]
public ActionResult MyController(MyControllerRequest request)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<MyControllerResult>();
    // do something
    return ServiceResult(response);
}
```

Now, how I can get the MyControllerResult and MyControllerRequest objects from a dll (or from a directory where are stored my referenced ddl) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check method parameters to identify request type and investigate method attributes in order to get result type. Assuming `ServiceControllerResult` attribute has `Type` property:

```
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    var parameters = method.GetParameters();
    if (parameters.Length != 1)
    {
        //decide what to do here
        throw new Exception("More than one parameter found");
    }

    var requestType = parameters[0].ParameterType;

    var serviceControllerResultAttribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<ServiceControllerResultAttribute>();
    if (serviceControllerResultAttribute == null)
    {
        //decide what to do here
        throw new Exception("ServiceControllerResultAttribute was not found");
    }

    var resultType = serviceControllerResultAttribute.Type;
}
```

Comment: ok, I got the parameter type but not the object inside the ServiceControllerResult.
Your method return the ServiceControllerResult object but I want the MyControllerResult object. Can you help me, please?

Comment: It doesn't return `ServiceControllerResult` it returns type stored in it. Can you post the code of `ServiceControllerResultAttribute`? Where does it store parameter (type) from constructor?